# Trouble with adding and editing answer

Tags: support, edits

Sometimes I have trouble with adding and editing answers on Stack Overflow.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23878759/685467) is the post with trouble. When I try to edit post it ends up with:

> An error occurred submitting the answer

Comment: Looks like the standard "paranoid proxy blocks SQL in HTTP requests" issue.